# Use of Qt standard icons from within Qt Creator

Tags: windows-7, icons, qt-creator

I would like to use the Qt Standard icons ([as here](http://standards.freedesktop.org/icon-naming-spec/icon-naming-spec-latest.html)). I have found many examples how to [set the icons programmatically](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/5199) (runtime in code).

<strike>However, how could I set the "standard icon name" (e.g. `application-exit`) in Qt Creator? This [blog here](http://5in4.de/blog/2012/02/07/using-standard-icons-in-qt-designer-and-qt-creator/) says, I do simply set the theme to the respective name. But I do not have such a theme property, I'd get a popup with a resource (screenshot below).</strike>

Where is the **right place to apply the "standard name"** (e.g. `application-exit`)?

Update from 2.4.x to Qt Creator 2.5.2 gives me the "theme" property from the above blog, but still no visible icons yet. **What else is required to make the icons visible?**

[image: Theme now available with Creator 2.5.2]

Remark Qt 4.8.1, now updated to 2.5.2, Windows 7

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Theme icons are only supported on Linux/X11. On Windows and OS X, you have to provide your own icons.

The solution to this problem is to set the theme name in QtCreator (as in your example). Then you have to provide icons of the same Alias under Prefix ":/icons" in your resources. You can leverage icons from sets available in the public domain, e.g. the popular Tango icon set.

If you only target the Windows platform, the theme setting will be of no use for you. If you target both Linux/X11 and other platforms, with this solution you get the native icons on one system and the icons you provide yourself on the others.

**You can find a very good explanation on how to do it here:**
http://mithatkonar.com/wiki/doku.php/qt/icons

Comment: In other operating systems there is a considerably large body of standard icons to be used on toolbars, etc. And there are icon themes for these. For example: http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Tango_icons http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/?content=122078 As you can see, it is a pretty nice concept because all applications that use these standard icons nicely fit into any desktop environment that is also customizable by the user.

Comment: Please note that my previous comments were replies to comments now deleted. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 8):

@ypnos suggested a great link with multiple approaches to solve the problem. I favorite the last one - [Creating a custom icon theme](http://mithatkonar.com/wiki/doku.php/qt/icons#custom_theme_using_qiconfromtheme). The author states three Pros (*Available to all platforms*, *Excellent resizing*, *Covers all needed icons*), and two Cons (*Not consistent with system icon theme*, *Pain in the ass to implement*). **Here I suggest improvements to get rid of the Cons.**

I've cloned the Tango iconset from github. Repository https://github.com/ppinard/qtango already features the *index.theme* file. But mainly, it brings a Python script `generate_rcc.py`, which can generate the `*.qrc` file automatically. I just had to change the arguments of `subprocess.check_call()` from `'--binary'` and `'--compress'` to `'-binary'` and `'-compress'`. The generated file contained absolute paths, but that's easy to Find&Replace. One can use this script to any iconset - first laborious step is solved.

Now, using the "Theme" property, you can define the icons in the Qt Designer, as already shown in the question. For those developing under Linux, *system* icons will show right in the Designer (suppose the iconset uses standard icon names). That's the native look (icons will be configurable in your system settings). That frees you from the `ui->action_Open->setIcon(...)` coding.

And the final tweak is to set the theme *before* ui setup.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
  QMainWindow(parent)
{
#ifdef _WIN32
  QIcon::setThemeName("tango");
#endif

  ui = new Ui::MainWindow;
  ui->setupUi(this);

  ...
  // NO NEED FOR ui->action_Open->setIcon(...)
}
```

The `#ifdef` can of course be adjusted to target all needed platforms, or omitted to force the same icons on all platforms including Linux.

**As a result, this approach avoids all laborious coding and the result is consistent with the system icons at least on Linux.**

Answer (score -3):

Unfortunately, this option of icon theme through Qt Designer is not available on Windows.

Comment: Do you mean it is not working under Windows? Because - as the screenshot above shows - it is possible to set the theme. Not available would mean for me, the option is not available at all. And is this considered a bug or is this a design decision of the Qt team? Any references giving some more details?