# How to update uic?

Tags: qt

I'm using on Linux the *Qt User Interface Compiler version 4.7.4* together with

[image]

But when I try to use theme icon [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12299626/1778537) I get errors

```
uic: Error in line 366, column 37 : Unexpected attribute theme
File 'textfinder.ui' is not valid
```

I read that the problem is during the conversion from XML files to generate the h files.

I guess that updating something could fix this. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Qt 4.7.x doesn't support icon themes.

Your options are:

- Remove the theme from your GUI, OR
- Upgrade to Qt 4.8.6 if you are maintaining an old project. (However, if you are starting a new project, you should upgrade to Qt 5.3.2 instead)

Comment: Strange. Why I have 4.7.x if the Help shows Based on 5.3.2? The Qt Creator is not related with the Qt versions? Please, could you tell me what should I update? Thanks.

Comment: @Sigur Qt is a C++ library. Your application is implemented using the Qt library; Qt Creator is also an application implemented using the Qt library. Qt Creator can manage many different versions of Qt at the same time. How did you install Qt? How did you install Qt Creator?

Comment: I installed it from here https://qt-project.org/downloads but I don't know if I already had some Qt libs before (I believe yes since from a long time ago I'm compiling TeXstudio).